# Firebase Admin SDK causing build error in React

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I added Firebase Admin SDK to a react project (I used create-react-app if that makes a difference). I'm just testing it out so I just initialize Firebase in index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<APP-NAME>.firebaseio.com/"
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Everything else in the project is essentially untouched. I go to run `npm run build` so I can deploy the project to Firebase hosting and get the following failed to compile error

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'request' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/shelf/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database

Any ideas what is the issue here or what I should do to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: The Firebase Admin SDK is meant for server-side applications, not client-side applications. You should use the standard Firebase client SDK (`firebase` not `firebase-admin`) in your React app.

Comment: @jacobawenger I have a server.js file that handles a POST request at a given url. Wouldn't I need the admin sdk for that?

Comment: The code sample you provided is client-side code, right? It uses "react-dom" after all. Is there a reason why you cannot use the client-side Firebase library and need to use the Admin SDK?

Comment: To authenticate sever with firebase so I can store data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Admin SDK is intended to be un on NodeJS, hence why it is trying to require `request`.

Please use the [Firebase Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) package for your React App.